# After changing namespace in UserControl files, ...g.cs files get errors

Tags: wpf

I copied three classes in from another WPF project and then **changed their namespaces**.

Now when I run the project, I get **errors in the ".g.cs" files** which say that the namespace is incorrect. I change this namespace but when I compile and run again, the ".g.cs" files get regenerated and overwritten with the old namespace version and I get the error again.

What are the files and **how can I make them be regenerate from the *current* files** instead of some cache that its obviously holding somewhere?

I deleted the \bin and \obj directories and rebuilt but still get the errors.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The .g.cs file is generated from the .xaml file. You need to change the x:class= attribute in your .xaml file to match the new namespace-qualified class name; then the .g.cs will be generated correctly on next compile. (Don't manually change the .g.cs file -- you'll only frustrate yourself.)

For example, if you previously had this in your .cs:

```
namespace Foo {
    class Bar { ...
```

and this in your .xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Foo.Bar" ...
```

And then you changed your namespace:

```
namespace Baz {
    class Bar { ...
```

Then you would need to change your .xaml file to:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Baz.Bar" ...
```

Comment: that was it: just needed to chnage the the x:class= entries and all was fine again, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Another possible cause is if you have any `xmlns:xx` namespaces in your xaml which you neglected to update when changing a namespace, then this will also cause an invalid using statement in the g.cs file.

Comment: +1 This was the cause for me. The automatically generated `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Some.App.Namespace"` was incorrect and pointing to thte wrong namespace.

Answer (score 7):

I found another way to solve this by deleting your 'obj' folder and rebuilding.

Comment: I had it all fine locally and failing on the build server - had to log into the build server and delete the obj folder...

Answer (score 4):

I had defined XML namespace shortcuts in my AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://www.example.com/wpf", "MyCorp.Wpf.OldNamespace")]
```

where the old namespace was still present.
Searching through all my *.xaml files obviously did not help …

After fixing the shortcuts, the error went away immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update the namespace of the class in the `x:Class` attribute on `UserControl` in the XAML too?

Failing that, have you tried rebuilding the project?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and tried deleting the `obj` and `bin` folders, but that would not work.  It finally compiled when I selected `Project > Clean` and then `Project > Build`.  There must be some Visual Studio cache somewhere else on my system.