# Auto generated view.g.cs page keeps including old using statements?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm having a pretty difficult time with my resources within the view pages.

The auto generated view.g.cs page keeps including old using statements and I can't get it to stop. I have about 12 views and it will only do it on the first one, but then I delete that file completely and it then adds them to the next view. I've tried recreating the views and but the first one with the generated file still fails. I then set the build option to none, cleaned, rebuilt, and back to page, and it still happens!

I've tried deleting the actual generated files in the obj folder but they just get created again and the first view in my list then screws up again.

Any way around this? I think I've exhausted my options other then recreating the project but I'd prefer not to do this. Any other way to fix the generated files?

Cheers.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955646/after-changing-namespace-in-usercontrol-files-g-cs-files-get-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue, I had two warnings that said the new namespace was declared twice in the same file... builds successfully.

Cheers.

Comment: Good that you tracked this down.

Answer (score 3):

Try right-clicking on the XAML file and "Run custom tool".

This should generate the new, up-to-date .q.cs files.

**EDIT:**

Also, make sure that your own XAML and code-behind file is correct. The best way to do this is to perform a recursive search for the old namespace in all the files *.* in project directory (most appropiate part of it, for example: com.company.product.OldNameOfFeature - search for OldNameOfFeature). If there are any XAML or code files you'll need to fix them.

**EDIT 2**

This search should be done using external application outside Visual Studio, for example TotalCommander.

How to search in TotalCommander:

[image]

Comment: then it's likely that there is still an error somewhere in xaml or .cs. Do the views open in the designer without an error?

Comment: They open fine, no errors, that actual namespace it pulls into the generated file doesn't even exist anymore... and when I build and get the error in the generated file if I delete the using statements and rebuild and F5 I can run the program, but the next time I build they show up again.

Comment: @bl4kh4k Perform a recursive search for the old namespace in all the files \*.\* in project directory (most appropiate part of it, say:  com.company.product.OldNameOfFeature - then search for OldNameOfFeature). Are there any files that aren't auto-generated?

Comment: Nothing comes up, if I close the autogenerated file, that find doesn't even show up, not until I build the solution again. Very strange.

Comment: @bl4kh4k Maybe you did you search inside Visual studio? Don't do that, use external application like TotalCommander. If you did use external application, then I don't know what else could help. I had this situation once and above suggestions helped me. +1 for the question though since it turns out not to be as uncommon as I thought.

Comment: I did do it in visual studio, just downloaded TotalCommander 7.57a and see a lot of options. Not sure how to use it yet, any quick suggestions on how to get the recursive search going, I pointed it to the project directory.

Comment: @bl4kh4k The defaults are almost OK, just set *.* as a file mask, enable checbox "find text" and type OldNamespace in the TextBox

Comment: I meant `*.*` as a file mask - see the screenshot

Comment: Strange, the program i had just downloaded looks nothing like your screenshot, probably grabbed the wrong piece of software.

Comment: NVM, found the search feature.

Comment: Too bad. I guess you'll have to start a new project and move your files :(

Comment: Bummer... maybe it'll go away someday lol. Thanks for your help though... I'll give you a mark for the great support! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you downgraded from .NET Core 6 to .NET Core 3.1, you need to fix your .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
```

Remove the "<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>" line.